# Numerical groups under birational morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f : X \to Y$ is birational morphism of smooth projective varieties.  Is true that $N^1(X) = f^\ast N^1(Y) \oplus \bigoplus \mathbb R \cdot [E_i]$, with $E_i$ ranges over exceptional divisors?